# How to understand this strange grep command with “--” symbol

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I get strange results when run the following grep command, first the content of "1.txt" is like this:

```
401 f
-- -----
```

Then when use `cat 1.txt | grep -v -- --`, the result is `401 f`, the command `cat 1.txt | grep -v -- -`, the result is also `401 f`. I know the `--` in first field is the filter pattern for grep, So I think `--` and `-` in the second field may both mean the stdout, right?. Then I run `cat 1.txt | grep -v --`, here I omit the stdout, but it is wrong, the info is `Try 'grep --help' for more information`. While I also run `cat 1.txt | grep -v -`, and this works, the result is `401 f`.

To further get the difference between `--` and `-` in grep, I run `cat 1.txt | grep --`, it shows `Try 'grep --help' for more information`. the `cat 1.txt | grep -` gets the result `-- -----`.

BTW, I have tried

1. `cat 1.txt | grep -v '--' --`
2. `cat 1.txt | grep -v '--' -`
3. `cat 1.txt | grep -v '--'`
4. `cat 1.txt | grep -v '-'`
5. `cat 1.txt | grep '--'`
6. `cat 1.txt | grep '-'`

Finally, I get the same corresponding results.

My question may be

1. what is the difference between `--` and `-` in the second field?
2. Why can not I use `--` pattern to get `-- -----` in the line?

Comment: `--` without quotes means "end of options"

Comment: @M.M quotes doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

`--` in utilities which use getopt is used to signal the end of options.

From the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html):

> The special argument "--" forces an end of option-scanning regardless of the scanning mode.

So in practice your first `--` argument will be ignored. If you want to grep for `--` you need to `grep .... -- --`

Comment: in `grep -v -- bla`, does the `--` mean end of options, or is it the parameter to `-v`  (and in the first case does `bla` become the parameter for `-v`)

Comment: @M.M `-v` does not accept parameters. Grep invocation is `grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]`. `blah` is still the pattern and `-v` is still the only option.

Answer (score 2):

You get what you get, because you use "-v", which means 'show anything that doesnt match'.

About -- aka. double-dash:

The double-dash is a signal to the underlying getopt library, that handles the parsing of command line options, that everything after the double-dash must be treated as a literal string, instead of an argument, regardless of the leading dash. 
Eg.

- 'grep -v test' will look for all lines not matching 'test' on stdin.
- 'grep -- -v test' will look for all lines matching "-v" in file test

Your grep is basically looking for *anything not "-"*.